# Fujifilm Smart Shot Supreme

Tags: fujifilm

I am new to film photography and got a Fujifilm smart shot supreme. I have successfully used and rewinded one roll of film before. This is my second one and I had 36 exposures on the roll. I switched the automatic rewind button and it worked fine until getting to the 26th exposure and it won’t continue to roll back. The sound of it rewinding still goes but it doesn’t do anything. Not sure how to fix it, any help is appreciated!